# CKEditor 4 - Focus a widget with keydown and keyup

Tags: jquery, plugins, accessibility, screen-readers, ckeditor4.x

Is there a way to focus on a widget in CKEditor 4 with the up and down keys? The right and left keys focus.

Accessibility: It's usual for screen-reader users to use the up and down keys while navigating the editor, and CK is ignoring the widgets in this case.

Comment: I tried the demo on https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/ and pressing Alt+F10 moves my keyboard focus to the toolbar, TAB moves to the different "mini" toolbars, then left/right **and** up/down moves me between buttons within the toolbar. You can see the keyboard shortcuts at https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/shortcuts.html#accessibility

Comment: Hello, @slugolicious! My point is the widgets, not the toolbar buttons.

Widgets are special rich content units in that they are groups of elements which are treated as a single entity inside the editor.

But thanks anyway!

Comment: Having the definition of "widget" would be helpful in your question. Is there a "widget" on the demo page? If not, do you have a working example?

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/simplebox.html

Comment: Using the "simple box" example, can you explain what is not working? It'd be better for you to explain that in your question and not in this comment section. I could TAB to the editor then TAB to the text box. I could also use up/down arrow keys to get to the text box. I was using NVDA screen reader.